# Weird top margin on top of my page despite having no h1's and body margin set to 0px

Tags: html, css

**Live Example Up at**

http://geovillageva.com/

I have a weird margin problem up top. I have set body margin to 0px, and cannot identify where the margin is coming from using Inspect Element.

**HTML of Header**

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="/image/header.png" alt="GeoVillage Banner" style="width:500px;height:64px;">
</div>
```

**CSS Of Header**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#header{
    display:block;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-image: url(/image/headerbackground.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

If you want the html of the whole page, do inspect element on the webpage. I have coded with PHP and it is extremely messy with all the variables ect.

Comment: Take a look at your rendered source code (view-source:http://geovillageva.com/). As you can see, the HTML is invalid and there are multiple root `html` tags. That is what is causing the problem.

Comment: `-=<!DOCTYPE html>` - what's the `-=`?

Answer (score 0):

I see **~=** 
below body tag and above link to css. Remove that extra.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin and padding for body and html, set it in div's
Also delete this symbols  https://yadi.sk/d/vq-uOlwZ3CarQV

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. Your html structure is wrong.

currently it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GeoVillage - A Community</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="defaultstyling.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/image/logo.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        -=<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/navbarstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

but it should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GeoVillage - A Community</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="defaultstyling.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/image/logo.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/navbarstyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

Try this and I think it will work.